# c# Jquery succes function not called after calling Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I try to execute this code that I would like to use in my website. I copied it from the book "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515).

This is Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationTestjQuery._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#MainContent_ButtonSearch").click(function () {
            // hide employee details
            $("empDetails").hide("slow");

            var empId = $("#MainContent_TextBoxEmpId").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
                data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId.toString() + "'}",
                cashe: false,
                succes: function (data) {
                    $("#textId").html(data.d.ID);
                    $("#textName").html(data.d.FullName);
                    $("#textTitle").html(data.d.Title);
                    $("#textDepartment").html(data.d.Department);

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error calling the webservice.");
                }

            });
            $("#empDetails").show("slow");
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Employee Lookup</h2>
<hr />
Enter Employee Id
<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmpId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
    <br />
    <input id="ButtonSearch" type="button" value="Search" runat="server" />

    <div id="empDetails" style="display: none;margin-top: 40px"> 
        <h2>Employee Details</h2>
        <hr />
        <b>ID:</b>&nbsp;<span id="textId"></span><br />
        <b>Name:</b>&nbsp;<span id="textName"></span><br />
        <b>Title:</b>&nbsp;<span id="textTitle"></span><br />
        <b>Department:</b>&nbsp;<span id="textDepartment"></span><br />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The ajax-call calls EmployeeService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace WebApplicationTestjQuery
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for EmployeeService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class EmployeeService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Employee GetEmployeeById(string employeeId)
        {
            //simulate name-lookup
            return new Employee(employeeId);

        }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee(string empId)
        {

            //simulate lookup employee
            this.ID = empId;
            this.FullName = "Roy C.";
            this.Title = "Webdeveloper";
            this.Department = "CBS";
        }

        public Employee() { }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the EmployeeService is very simple code that returns employee-properties. It fills out the properties correct. I can view that in the debugger of Visual Studio. However, when the cursor returns to the ajax-call in Default.aspx, the return-function is not called. Neither the error-function is called. I tried to debug it with Chrome Devtools, but the only thing I can see it just returns nothing. It doesn't cause an error. "Pause On Caught Exceptions" is checked.

In Internet Explorer "Active Scripting" is enabled. JQuery works well without calling the service. I already tried solutions that are related to this problem via StackOverflow. No succes however.

I already spent days to this problem. Please help.

Roy

Work environment employer:
Visual Studio 2010
Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m
Windows Server 2003 does not call succes or error (my work environment)

Home environment:
Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7
Internet Explorer 11 
(does not call succes, but does call error (my private environment))

Comment: the spelling of success and cache is wrong in ajax function

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
        data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId.toString() + "'}",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#textId").html(data.d.ID);
            $("#textName").html(data.d.FullName);
            $("#textTitle").html(data.d.Title);
            $("#textDepartment").html(data.d.Department);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error calling the webservice.");
        }

    });
```

Comment: OMG... this is really bad. I was expecting the compiler would error. But is doesn't. So it is that simple.... thank you! Now I can rely on VS (but not on myselve anymore)